# Raise event of mocking object and passing there as argument object used for calling method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, mocking, moq

I have an interface `IPeakCommunication`, and derived class `PeakCommunication`. Inside derived class I have an implementation of method `Send(RequestData request)` which do something, and as I expect invokes event `RequestReceived` and passing there argument `request`.

I would to create unit tests for some classes which interact with `IPeakCommunication`, and call `Send(RequestData request)` method. But I have no idea how to create a Mock which takes an object from arguments and use it for invoking `RequestReceived` event.

```
public interface IPeakCommunication : IDisposable
{
#region Delegates
delegate void PeakRequestReceivedHandler(RequestData data);
#endregion

#region Events
event PeakRequestReceivedHandler? RequestReceived;
#endregion

#region Methods
void Send(RequestData data);
#endregion
}
```

The code which I tried to make:

```
var mockCommunication = new Mock<IPeakCommunication>();
mockCommunication.Setup(x => x.Send(It.IsAny<RequestData>()))
    .Raises(x => x.RequestReceived += null, new object[] { /*argument from Send()?*/ } );
```

Comment: And this doesn't help? https://github.com/devlooped/moq/wiki/Quickstart#events

Comment: Oh, I see: You need to pass the _actual_ argument to `Send` as EventArg ... that's the _one_ example that's missing ...

Comment: @Fildor Yes, correct Moq. As I understood in those examples where the event call is used, new objects (EventArgs) were used. My goal is to capture an object from a method and use it in an event call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Callback`:

```cs
var mockCommunication = new Mock<IPeakCommunication>();

// Setup with callback which uses Raise
mockCommunication.Setup(x => x.Send(It.IsAny<RequestData>()))
    .Callback((RequestData rd) => 
        mockCommunication.Raise(c => c.RequestReceived += null, rd));

// Act
var obj = mockCommunication.Object;
// sample subscriber:
obj.RequestReceived += rd => Console.WriteLine(rd.Data);
obj.Send(new RequestData { Data = 42 }); // Prints 42

// sample data object
public class RequestData
{
    public int Data { get; set; }
}
```

[Demo @dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cqslnw)